# Probability of grabbing a novel from your bag two days in a row

Tags: probability

> Suppose you have five books in your book bag. Three are novels, one is biography, and one is a poetry book. Today you grab one book out without looking, and return it later. Tomorrow, you do the same thing. What is the probability that you grab a novel both days?

I thought it would be $$ 3 / 5 $$
But that would be the chances of getting novels out of the other books? How would I do this? Multiply 2 to 3/5? Also I am kind of struggling with probability, is their a way I can do the probability problem in a simpler way?

Comment: It's $\frac 35$ to get a novel on a single day!  probabilities multiply across independent observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of $3/5$ is the probability of grabbing a novel one of the days ($3$ of the $5$ books are novels).

But you need to grab a novel *both* days. This gives you

$$\frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{3}{5} = \frac{9}{25}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering

Answer (score 1):

Your answer would be correct if the question were asking the probability of choosing a novel any given day. But the probability of choosing a novel on day 1 and *again* on day 2 is (probability of the first)*(probability of the second), which equals $(3/5)\cdot (3/5)=9/25$, or $0.36$.